# trying to concatenate session variables in Java script for snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two databases $a_database and $b_database. I am trying to see how to concatenate these two. I have used "Binds" and also "if else". Any other method that I can concatenate?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use JavaScript to concatenate two Snowflake session variables. You can do it there, but it would be more complex than doing it just issuing SQL statements.

```
set a_database = 'Hello';
set b_database = ', world';

set c_concatenated = (select $a_database || $b_database);

select $c_concatenated;
```

The key thing is when you're assigning something other than a simple literal value, you have to wrap a select statement in parenthesis.